# Нужно изменить формат даты на dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php"); 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `message` (`name`, `surname`, `patronymic`, `date`, `text`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['surname']."','".$_POST['patronymic']."','".$_POST['date']."','".$_POST['text']."')");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Martel|Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="col-lg-6" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="surname">Фамилия</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="surname" id="surname">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Имя</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="name" id="name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="patronymic">Отчетсво</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="patronymic" id="patronymic">
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Дата рождения</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control qwerty" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Дата">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Биография</label>
  <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7" id="text"></textarea>
</div>
 <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
</form>
</div>
<hr />
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-3" >Дата рождения</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Фамилия</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Имя</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Отчество</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Биография</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,date,surname,name,patronymic,text FROM message"); 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))


{ // выводим данные

echo "<tr>\n\t<td>".$row["id"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["date"]."

</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["surname"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row
["name"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["patronymic"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>
"."".$row["text"]."</td>"."\n\t"."</tr>"."\n";
}

mysql_close();

?>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</header>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL есть удобная функция запроса даты и времени: DATE_FORMAT().
В приведённом ниже примере дата будет подаваться в виде ДД.ММ.ГГГГ

**%d** - День месяца, 2 цифры с ведущим нулём

**%m** - Порядковый номер месяца с ведущим нулём

**%Y** - год

Между ними могут быть почти любые символы, я поставил точки:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%d.%m.%Y"), surname, name, patronymic, text FROM message");
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

---

Ещё вариант: оператор date().

Преобразует дату в текст.

Описание [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Собсно, вот:

```
$result=mysql_query(
    "SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') as `date`,surname,name,patronymic,text FROM message"
);
```

А еще неплохо бы переписать Ваш `db_connect.php` на коннект mysqli или PDO.

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: Не знаете ли Вы случайно, как сделать сортировку таблицы по заголовку и чтобы сортировался только определенный столбец, весь день найти не могу решение

Comment: @Artemfomkin, Вы можете попробовать сформулировать вопрос как-нибудь понятно и желательно пример при этом привести. И, насколько я понимаю, имеет смысл вынести это в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: При нажатии на заголовок соответствующего столбца данные в таблице должны сортироваться по возрастанию/убыванию информации в конкретном столбце

Comment: Есть 6 столбцов id, дата рождения, фамилия, имя, отчество и я когда нажимаю на столбец id то сортироваться должен только столбец id по возрастанию/убыванию остальные не изменяются. Пробывал через DataTables но он сортирует все значения.